# Is safe to use rsync -z option for database sync (Postgresql binary replication)?

Tags: rsync, compression

I see that this option is good for slow connections, because it enables the compression. But what this really means?

Will this option compress the data only during the transfer?

Or the files in the destination will be compressed?

The files in the origin will be temporary compressed at the origin folder causing damages on a database for example? Or can I run it safe for copy the database files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Manual page explains, it is only used during transfer:

> `-z, --compress`
>
> With  this  option, rsync compresses the file data as it is sent to the destination machine, which reduces the amount of data being transmitted -- something that is useful over a slow connection.
> [...]

Backing up "living" database files is never good idea and you should always stop database before touching the files, not only when you want the compression.

Comment: In fact i am using a option in a database that recommends the use of rsync to copy the files, so not a problem in my case. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Binary_Replication_Tutorial take a look at it. Starting Replication with only a Quick Master Restart

Comment: Well, that is different story. But you see in the first occurrence that the database is off and in the second case, you switch the database to special mode to handle that. The compression here should not matter.

Comment: Yes database is switched on the special mode... i do this a lot of times, i am consider to start to use the -z option capabilities. Thank you for your help.